# Combine 2 queries together

Tags: sql

I am struggling to work out combining a query that should give me 3 columns of Month, total_sold_products and drinks_sold_products

Query 1:

```
Select month(date), count(id) as total_sold_products 
from Products 
where date between '2022-01-01' and '2022-12-31'
```

Query 2

```
Select month(date), count(id) as drinks_sold_products 
from Products where type = 'drinks' and date between '2022-01-01' and '2022-12-31'
```

I tried the union function but it summed count(id) twice and gave me only 2 columns

Many thanks!

Comment: Use one query only and conditional count (for example with CASE)

Comment: And please tag your DBMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Union is for attaching sets of data on top of each other. You need conditional aggregation or a join. See below.

```
    SELECT MONTH(date), 
        COUNT(*) AS total_sold_products,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'drinks' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS drinks_sold_products, 
        FORMAT((CASE 
             WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 
                COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'drinks' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(*) 
                 ELSE 0 END),
        'P') AS Percentage
    FROM Products 
    WHERE date BETWEEN'2022-01-01' AND '2022-12-31'
    GROUP BY MONTH(date)
```

Comment: what a legend! Thank you very much!

Comment: Follow up question if I may, @ClearlyClueless.  I tried to calculate the percentage from the drinks_sold_products/total_sold_products but I get an error. I am not sure how to do that.
I tried the round() , tried straight division, but it's not working.

Comment: You would need to use the exact same select criteria and account for 0 as a divisor.  I've adjusted the solution above. There are better ways to do this, mind you, and certainly cleaner ones.